Term for a person who can access someone's information on their behalf, but not make decisions for them
I work for an insurance administrator, and I am creating a form for the clients to grant access to someone else (usually, but not exclusively, a spouse) to have permission to access information from their file, but not to make any decisions on behalf of the client. For example, this person would have permission for my organization to explain to them why a given claim was rejected, but would not have signing authority for submitting a claim, or be able to authorize us to reset the password for the member's account.
I've found several terms that seem close to this, but don't quite fit, or are too legalistic:

Custodian (would refer to someone who has a responsibility to keep the information safe)

Delegate (can make decisions on behalf of someone)

Deputy (can make decisions on behalf of someone)

Designated contact (not clear enough)

Fiduciary (too legalistic, and can make decisions on behalf of someone)

Guardian (would refer to someone who has a responsibility to keep the information safe)

Information handler (seems to refer to individuals acting as part of an organization rather than private individuals)

Information Proxy

Proxy (can make decisions on behalf of someone)

Representative (can make decisions on behalf of someone)

Stand-in (can make decisions on behalf of someone)

Steward (would refer to someone who has a responsibility to keep the information safe)

Surrogate (can make decisions on behalf of someone)

Trustee (can make decisions on behalf of someone)


The closest to what I'm looking for is an "Information proxy", but this doesn't seem to be an existing term as far as I can tell. I was also thinking of including the word "Privilege" in the term.
Any ideas or advice would be appreciated!

One for your legal department I think.

As per @KillingTime, you may be reinventing the wheel and of course need a legalistic term. The legal assignment must already be labeled in the insurance industry. I'd vote for Confidante actually.

I don't think there's a term for this relationship. In the iPhone Health app, you can share your information with a friend/relative, and the prompt is "Share with".

"Monitor", "auditor", and "investigator" all seem like they somewhat convey the meaning desired, but as someone else commented, these are probably not terms that would satisfy the legal profession.

"Observer", "viewer", or similar would apply. Or I guess "trusted observer", "permitted observer", etc. In software engineering you might have "read-only access". But why exactly is the person granted access? To check or query status, to take additional actions based on the status, for accounting or forensic purposes, acting as an assistant to the main policy holder and reporting to them? It's bad information management to give someone access for no reason. And understanding why they need (limited) access is the key to finding the most precise term term.

@StuartF Has the right idea, I think. I give my sister access to my medical records in case I become incapacitated. I give my financial advisor access to my financial records to inform his advice. There's no one-size-fits-all term for these relationships.

One of my healthcare providers has a similar form and the label they chose was "Approved HIPAA Representative"
